# Insert comma(,) into a value using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Hello there i have problem in jQuery. Suppose i have a value like 20000. And i want the value like 20,000 that after two number a comma will be inserted. I can't do it using jQuery. Please anyone help me out.

Comment: what if you'll have `345000`? what than?

Comment: Not sure why there is the php tag if you want a jQuery solution, but anyway if you are using PHP then [`number_format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php) is the easiest solution IMO.

Comment: Thanks to give me valuable links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said you want the comman inserted "after two numbers", I'm going to assume you have the easy case where you know that your input is a 5 digit number and don't want a more generic number formatting solution. In that case you can do something just like:

```
var num = 20000;

num = num.toString();
num = num.substr(0,2) + ',' + num.substr(2);
// Now num === "20,000"
```

Note that `20,000` will only read as twenty-thousand in certain locales. It could be read as just twenty in many locales, but `20000` will be read correctly by anyone who understands Arabic numerals.